# An example of a ring homomorphism that sends identity to nonidentity.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can anyone give me an example of a nontrivial ring homomorphism among commutative rings that sends identity to nonidentity?

I know that if we assume it is a ring homomorphism among integral domain, or we assume the ring homomorphism is surjective, then the image of multiplicative identity must be multiplicative identity.

Comment: Does "Identity" mean "neuter element"? For example, $1$ if we're talking about $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @David yes, the multiplicative identity for rings.

Comment: It is a convention in commutative algebra, that a ring homomorphism maps the identity of the source ring to the identity of the target ring.

Comment: Take $R\to R\oplus R$?

Comment: @Bernard Not everywhere.

Comment: @Andy As far as I'm aware, all ring homomorphism must take the multiplicative identity of the domain into the multiplicative identity of the image.

Comment: @Adayah: Maybe, but I stick to Bourbaki's conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ defined by $f(n)=3\bar n$.

Answer (score 0):

The standard example is the map $R\to R\times R$ defined by $r\mapsto(r,0)$, where $R$ is any ring with identity.